# Use disabled in reactive form

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

This is my form :

```
damageInfoForm = new FormGroup({
cause : new FormControl('', Validators.required),
subCause : new FormControl('', Validators.required)
 })
```

the field subCause is related to the field cause that's why **I want to disable the field subCause if the field cause is empty**

So I edit my html like that :

```
  <form class="k-form k-form-inline " [formGroup]="damageInfoForm">
                  
                        <div class="col-md-4 no-padding-left">
                          <div [ngClass]="{ 'spaced':true }">
                            <span>cause</span>
          
                            <kendo-combobox  [data]="causes" [disabled]="generalDataForm.get('mainCause').value==''" formControlName="cause" class="form-control">
                            </kendo-combobox>
                            <span>Sub cause</span></span>
                            <kendo-combobox  [data]="subCauses" [disabled]="damageInfoForm.get('cause').value==''" formControlName="subCause" class="form-control">
                            </kendo-combobox>
  </div>
 </div>
</form>
```

It works but it gives me the warning `It looks like you're using the disabled attribute with a reactive form directive`

Comment: Add a default value... new FormControl('', Validators.required, {disabled: true})

Answer (score 2):

You will have to disable the field by code, not in the html. This can be done the following way when listening to valueChanges of the cause field:

```
damageInfoForm.get('cause').valueChanges.subscribe(v => {
   if(!v) {
     damageInfoForm.get('subCause').disable();
   }
   else {
     damageInfoForm.get('subCause').enable();
   }});
```